# Force Verbose Mode in Windows DEL Command

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I sometimes delete masses of files on multiple computers with the Windows command line, with the `DEL` command, and on some the function is verbose (i.e. outputs the files it deletes as it goes), while on others it's not the case. Is there a way to force the command line utility to always display its progress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the **del** and **erase** commands will be silent unless you include the **/s** argument to delete all files in all subdirectories.

One option is to simply delete the files one by one. Let's say you want to delete everything in the temp folder:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %A in ('dir /s /b "%TEMP%"') do del /Q "%A"
```

That will take a while to start up against 2 million files as it will need to list them first and then delete them one by one.

Another option is to use **Robocopy** and have it mirror an empty directory to delete the files you want. You will get verbose output as each file is deleted. Start with an empty directory (c:\empty) and run something similar to the following:

```
robocopy c:\empty c:\dir_with_files_to_be_deleted *files_you_want_to_delete.* /mir /v
```

Or, if you just want to delete all files in a single directory:

```
robocopy c:\empty c:\dir_to_empty /mir /v
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're deleting a whole directory, use **`rd/s/q`** (`rmdir /s /q`) instead.

Comment: Thanks, it is useful in some cases although right now I'm trying to delete certain files in a folder that contains over 2 million files.

Comment: This is faster probably because it does not echo each delete on the console.